# Selecting a iframe accessible only when another iframe is selected with Selenium + Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, iframe

I'm using Selenium libraries for Python and I want to click a button inside an iframe named "a", but this iframe is inside a `<div>` that is hidden by default and only becomes visible when a button inside an iframe named "b" is clicked. "a" is not a subframe of "b". When I use the "driver.switch_to.default_content" line, after clicking the button inside "b", the `<div>` containing the "a" becomes hidden again and the iframe can't be selected. How can I solve this problem?

```
cap["marionette"] = False


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('website.com')
driver.switch_to.frame(0)          #iframe b is the first one of the page
driver.find_element_by_id("button b").click()

browser.switch_to.default_content()
browser.switch_to.frame(2)      #iframe a is the third one of the page 
browser.find_element_by_id("button a").click()
```